# Does doubly transitive action imply transitive action?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we know that a group $G$ acts doubly-transitively on a set $X$, do we also know that it acts transitively on $X$?

I know that if a group $G$ acts doubly-transitively on a set $X$ that Stab$(y)$ acts transitively on $X-\{y\}$ for all $y\in X$. Can this be useful in showing the result I am looking for?

I'm currently trying to show that if a finite group $G$ acts doubly-transitively on a set $X$ where $|X|=n, n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}$, then $n(n-1)$ divides $|G|$. So I figure that if I know thats $G$ acts transitively on $X$, then I can say:

$\bullet$ $|X|$ divides $|G|$ , i.e. $n$ divides $|G|$.

$\bullet$ $|Stab(y)|$ divides $|X-\{y\}|$, and I haven't quite figured out yet how this will be helpful, but this is probably going to give me $n-1$ divides $|G|$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the definition of doubly-transitive allows that two elements in the pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are equal, i.e., $x=x'$. So the pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x,y')$
admit a $g\in G$ such that $gx = x$ and $gy = y'$ by double-transitivity.
In particular, any doubly transitive action is transitive. A very good reference is the text by K. Conrad on [Transitive group actions](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/transitive.pdf), where all details can be found.

Comment: Thank you for the book reference !

Comment: It's not a book; Keith Conrad calls it "blurbs". It discusses doubly-transitive actions in section $4$.